# Agile Methodology

Tags: architecture, agile

1. Will Solution Architecture be suited for Agile methodology?
2. Which architecture approach be best fit for agile implementation, Currently I'm assuming that Micro-Services Architecture be the best suite for Agile Methodology, Can anyone provide justifications for this?

Kindly help me in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't link the choice of software architecture (e.g. Micro-Services vs. Monolith) with the choice of software development lifecycle or project management (e.g. Agile vs. Waterfall).

A software architecture should be chosen based on the quality attributes of the product, taking into account the tradeoffs between performance, security, ease-of-use, availability, interoperability, maintainability, etc...

Software development procedures, management styles, and organization units should be chosen and built based on what makes the team most productive. A great Scrum team may prefer to do micro-services in one project, and a monolith in another project. Likewise, a company that follows a waterfall process may choose to break an application to microservices or leave it as a monolith.

The difference between Agile and Waterfall might be the way in which the architecture emerges: In Waterfall, people often do more architecture upfront, whereas in Agile, there is some architecture upfront, but more of the architecture emerges as requirements are discovered during the sprints.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Much Appreciated.

Comment: Leading to one more question, Is there any strategic way in agile to handle futuristic major design change in terms of performance degradation?

Comment: I don't have a perfect answer. Rebecca Wirfs-Brock is one author who has written on this topic (http://wirfs-brock.com/). But I can say that good architecture doesn't naturally arise from developers adding one feature at a time. Often we need a special architecting and reengineering effort. The Agile procedures do not take care of this on their own. People need to be educated about the important role of architecture.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Much appreciated!